# C - Function Only Working When Looped At Least 17 Times

Tags: c, loops, iteration, screen, x11

Before I proceed with the question, I would like to address that I am learning everything on my own and have no college experience. I cannot afford it. So if anyone knows a good resource they can point me to relating to this topic on a scientific level, I would greatly appreciate it!

I have noticed that when I run one of my functions that draws a colormap to the screen, it doesn't work on one call. The call has to be looped at least 17 times for it to actually draw the colormap to the screen.

I am programming for Linux in X11, and here is an example of my code that didn't work --->

```
Canvas_Draw(display, &canvas);
```

Though, it worked when I changed it to this --->

```
unsigned int number = 0;

while (number < 17) {
    Canvas_Draw(display, &canvas);
    number++;
}
```

It works as long as it loops at least 17 times. Yet, this is not the case for other functions like loading and decoding a file, even if it's large...or even off screen rendering. Could this have to do with the fact that this function is drawing an image to the screen? Here is the code for the function being called --->

```
GC gc_field;
XGCValues gc_values;
gc_field = XCreateGC(display, canvas->canvas, GCForeground, &gc_values);

XPutImage(display, canvas->canvas, gc_field, canvas->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, canvas->width, canvas->height);
XFlush(display);
```

Any help explaining this to me or even pointing me to a valid resource which explains this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

*Edit*

After Remaking it for this example, the significant number changed! It's no longer 17, but now 13! I also noticed with a different image, it did not require the function to be looped, while it still did on the first tested image!

*Note, the BMP Decoder only decodes 24-bit uncompressed BMP images.*

Here is a verifiable example --->

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

#define BYTE unsigned char
#define UINT unsigned int
#define ULONG unsigned long
#define COLOR unsigned int
#define ARRAY unsigned char*

typedef struct Position Position;
typedef struct Size Size;
typedef struct Array Array;
typedef struct Pixelmap Pixelmap;
typedef struct BMP BMP;
typedef struct Canvas Canvas;
typedef struct Panel Panel;

struct Position {
    int x, y;
};

struct Size {
    unsigned int width, height;
};

struct Array {
    ARRAY data;
    ULONG dataCount;
};

struct Pixelmap {
    unsigned int* pixels;
    UINT depth;
    Size size;
    UINT pixelCount;
};

struct BMP {
    UINT width;
    UINT height;
    UINT depth;
    UINT compressionType;
    unsigned int* pixels;
};

struct Canvas {
    int loaded;
    int x, y, width, height;
    COLOR forecolor, backcolor;
    Pixelmap *field;
    XImage *image;
    Window canvas;
};

struct Panel {
    int x, y, width, height, forecolor, backcolor;
    Window panel;
};

void Canvas_Load_BMP(Display *display, Canvas *canvas, BMP *bmp);
void Canvas_Render(Display* display, Canvas *canvas);
void Canvas_Draw(Display *display, Canvas *canvas);
BMP *BMPDecoder_Decode(Array *bmpData);
Array *BMPDecoder_Load_File(char* Path);
Pixelmap *Pixelmap_Create(Size size, UINT Depth);
int Pixelmap_Add_Pixel(Pixelmap *pMap, COLOR Pixel);
int ArrayComparator(ARRAY A, ARRAY B, UINT Size);
Array *Array_Create(ULONG Size);
UINT Array_To_UINT(ARRAY Integer);
COLOR Color_Alpha_Blend(COLOR color, COLOR BG);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Display* display;
    Screen* screen;
    int screenIndex;
    Size screenSize;
    Window window;
    XEvent event;
    GC gc_canvas;
    int x, y, width, height;
    Position w_position;
    Size w_size;
    int rendered = 0;
    const char* programName = "Image Display Test";

    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    screen = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(display);

    screenSize.width = screen->width;
    screenSize.height = screen->height;

    if (display == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open display!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    width = 800;
    height = 600;
    x = (screenSize.width/2) - (width/2);
    y = (screenSize.height/2) - (height/2);
    w_position.x = x;
    w_position.y = y;
    w_size.width = width;
    w_size.height = height;

    screenIndex = DefaultScreen(display);
    window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, RootWindow(display, screenIndex), x, y, width, height, 1, 0, 0xFFFFFF);

    XSelectInput(display, window, KeyPressMask | PropertyChangeMask | StructureNotifyMask | PointerMotionMask | ButtonPressMask);
    XMapWindow(display, window);
    XFlush(display);

    XStoreName(display, window, programName);

    XWindowChanges changes;
    changes.x = w_position.x;
    changes.y = w_position.y;
    XConfigureWindow(display, window, CWX | CWY, &changes);

    Panel cPanel;

    cPanel.x = 0;
    cPanel.y = 0;
    cPanel.width = width;
    cPanel.height = height;

    cPanel.panel = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, window, 0, 0, width, height, 0, 0x000000, 0xFF0000);

    XSelectInput(display, cPanel.panel, KeyPressMask | ButtonPressMask | StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(display, cPanel.panel);
    XFlush(display);

    int created = 0;

    Canvas canvas;

    int c_width = width/2;
    int c_height = height/2;

    canvas.canvas = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, cPanel.panel, width/2-(c_width/2), width/2-(c_width/2), c_width, c_height, 0, 0, 0x000000);

    canvas.x = x;
    canvas.y = y;
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    canvas.loaded = 0;

    XSelectInput(display, canvas.canvas, KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | ButtonPressMask | StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(display, canvas.canvas);
    XFlush(display);

    Size size;
    size.width = canvas.width;
    size.height = canvas.height;

    canvas.field = Pixelmap_Create(size, 4);

    UINT index = 0;

    while (index < canvas.width*canvas.height) {
        Pixelmap_Add_Pixel(canvas.field, 0x00000000);
        index++;
    }

    canvas.backcolor = 0x00000000;
    XSetWindowBackground(display, canvas.canvas, 0x000000);

    Array *bmpData = BMPDecoder_Load_File("/home/user/Example 1.bmp");
    BMP *bmp = BMPDecoder_Decode(bmpData);

    Canvas_Load_BMP(display, &canvas, bmp);

    Canvas_Render(display, &canvas);

    UINT number = 0;

    while(1) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);

        if (number < 13) {
            Canvas_Draw(display, &canvas);
            number++;
        }

        if (event.xany.window == window) {
            if (event.type == ConfigureNotify) {
                XWindowAttributes attributes;
                XGetWindowAttributes(display, window, &attributes);

                Size np_size;
                np_size.width = attributes.width;
                np_size.height = attributes.height;

                if (np_size.width > 0 && np_size.height > 0) {
                    cPanel.width = np_size.width;
                    cPanel.height = np_size.height;

                    XWindowChanges changes;
                    changes.width = np_size.width;
                    changes.height = np_size.height;
                    XConfigureWindow(display, cPanel.panel, CWWidth | CWHeight, &changes);
                }

                Position nc_position;
                nc_position.x = cPanel.width/2-(canvas.width/2);
                nc_position.y = cPanel.height/2-(canvas.height/2);

                canvas.x = nc_position.x;
                canvas.y = nc_position.y;

                XWindowChanges changes;
                changes.x = nc_position.x;
                changes.y = nc_position.y;
                XConfigureWindow(display, canvas.canvas, CWX | CWY, &changes);

                Canvas_Draw(display, &canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void Canvas_Load_BMP(Display *display, Canvas *canvas, BMP *bmp) {
    canvas->width = bmp->width;
    canvas->height = bmp->height;

    Size size;
    size.width = bmp->width;
    size.height = bmp->height;

    canvas->field = Pixelmap_Create(size, 4);

    char* data = calloc(bmp->width*bmp->height, 4);
    canvas->image = XCreateImage(display, DefaultVisual(display, 0), DefaultDepth(display, 0), ZPixmap, 0, data, bmp->width, bmp->height, 32, 0);

    XWindowChanges changes;
    changes.width = size.width;
    changes.height = size.height;
    XConfigureWindow(display, canvas->canvas, CWWidth | CWHeight, &changes);

    int x = 0;
    int y = bmp->height-1;
    UINT increment = 0;

    while (y > -1) {
        while (x < bmp->width) {
            Pixelmap_Add_Pixel(canvas->field, bmp->pixels[bmp->width*y+x]);
            x++;
        }
        x = 0;
        y--;
    }

    canvas->loaded = 1;
}

void Canvas_Render(Display* display, Canvas *canvas) {
    if (canvas->loaded == 0)
        return;

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while (y < canvas->height) {
        while (x < canvas->width) {
            XPutPixel(canvas->image, x, y, Color_Alpha_Blend(canvas->field->pixels[(canvas->width*y)+x], canvas->backcolor));
            x++;
        }
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }

    XFlush(display);
}

void Canvas_Draw(Display *display, Canvas *canvas) {
    if (canvas->loaded == 0)
        return;

    GC gc_field;
    XGCValues gc_values;
    gc_field = XCreateGC(display, canvas->canvas, GCForeground, &gc_values);

    XPutImage(display, canvas->canvas, gc_field, canvas->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, canvas->width, canvas->height);
    XFlush(display);
}

BMP *BMPDecoder_Decode(Array *bmpData) {
    BMP *bmp = malloc(sizeof(BMP));

    BYTE bheader[] = { 0x42, 0x4D };
    BYTE fSizeBytes[] = { bmpData->data[5], bmpData->data[4], bmpData->data[3], bmpData->data[2] };
    BYTE dataOffsetBytes[] = { bmpData->data[13], bmpData->data[12], bmpData->data[11], bmpData->data[10] };
    BYTE widthBytes[] = { bmpData->data[21], bmpData->data[20], bmpData->data[19], bmpData->data[18] };
    BYTE heightBytes[] = { bmpData->data[25], bmpData->data[24], bmpData->data[23], bmpData->data[22] };
    BYTE depthBytes[] = { 0x00, 0x00, bmpData->data[29], bmpData->data[28] };
    BYTE compressionTypeBytes[] = { bmpData->data[33], bmpData->data[32], bmpData->data[31], bmpData->data[30] };
    BYTE bitmapSizeBytes[] = { bmpData->data[37], bmpData->data[36], bmpData->data[35], bmpData->data[34] };

    ARRAY fheader = calloc(2, sizeof(BYTE));
    fheader[0] = bmpData->data[0];
    fheader[1] = bmpData->data[1];

    if (!ArrayComparator(fheader, bheader, 2)) {
        free(fheader);
        return NULL;
    }

    free(fheader);

    UINT fSize = Array_To_UINT(fSizeBytes);
    UINT dataOffset = Array_To_UINT(dataOffsetBytes);
    UINT width = Array_To_UINT(widthBytes);
    UINT height = Array_To_UINT(heightBytes);
    UINT depth = Array_To_UINT(depthBytes);
    UINT compressionType = Array_To_UINT(compressionTypeBytes);
    UINT bitmapSize = Array_To_UINT(bitmapSizeBytes);

    if (fSize != bmpData->dataCount)
        return NULL;

    if (fSize-dataOffset != bitmapSize)
        return NULL;

    int padding = (width*(depth/8))%4;

    if (padding != 0) {
        padding -= 4;
        padding *= -1;
    }

    bmp->width = width;
    bmp->height = height;
    bmp->depth = depth;
    bmp->compressionType = compressionType;

    bmp->pixels = calloc(width*height, sizeof(COLOR));

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    BYTE colorBytes[depth/8];

    while (y < height) {
        while (x < width) {
            colorBytes[0] = bmpData->data[dataOffset+(width*(depth/8))*y+y*padding+x*(depth/8)+2];
            colorBytes[1] = bmpData->data[dataOffset+(width*(depth/8))*y+y*padding+x*(depth/8)+1];
            colorBytes[2] = bmpData->data[dataOffset+(width*(depth/8))*y+y*padding+x*(depth/8)];

            bmp->pixels[width*y+x] = (0xFF & colorBytes[0]) << 24 | (0xFF & colorBytes[1]) << 16 | (0xFF & colorBytes[2]) << 8 | 0xFF;
            x++;
        }
        x = 0;
        y++;
    }

    return bmp;
}

Array *BMPDecoder_Load_File(char* Path) {
    FILE *fileptr;
    ARRAY buffer;
    ULONG filelen;
    UINT i = 0;

    fileptr = fopen(Path, "rb");
    fseek(fileptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    filelen = ftell(fileptr);
    rewind(fileptr);
    buffer = calloc(filelen, sizeof(BYTE));

    Array *data = Array_Create(filelen);

    while (i < filelen) {
        fread(data->data+i, 1, 1, fileptr);
        i++;
    }

    if (data->dataCount <= 0)
        return NULL;

    return data;
}

Array *Array_Create(ULONG Size) {
    Array *array = malloc(sizeof(Array));

    array->data = calloc(Size, sizeof(BYTE));
    array->dataCount = Size;

    return array;
}

Pixelmap *Pixelmap_Create(Size size, UINT Depth) {
    Pixelmap *pMap = malloc(sizeof(Pixelmap));

    pMap->depth = Depth;
    pMap->size = size;
    pMap->pixels = calloc(1, sizeof(Depth));
    pMap->pixelCount = 0;

    return pMap;
}

int Pixelmap_Add_Pixel(Pixelmap *pMap, COLOR Pixel) {
    UINT pixelCount = pMap->pixelCount+1;

    void *newPixels = realloc(pMap->pixels, sizeof(pMap->depth)*pixelCount);

    if (newPixels != NULL)
        pMap->pixels = newPixels;
    else
        return 0;

    pMap->pixelCount++;

    pMap->pixels[pixelCount-1] = Pixel;

    return 1;
}

int ArrayComparator(ARRAY A, ARRAY B, UINT Size) {
    int index = 0;

    while (index < Size) {
        if (A[index] != B[index])
            return 0;

        index++;
    }

    return 1;
}

UINT Array_To_UINT(ARRAY Integer) {
    return Integer[0] << 24 | Integer[1] << 16 | Integer[2] << 8 | Integer[3];
}

COLOR Color_Alpha_Blend(COLOR color, COLOR BG) {
    COLOR cred = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
    COLOR cgreen = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
    COLOR cblue = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
    COLOR alpha = color & 0xFF;

    COLOR bred = (BG >> 24) & 0xFF;
    COLOR bgreen = (BG >> 16) & 0xFF;
    COLOR bblue = (BG >> 8) & 0xFF;

    COLOR red = ((cred*alpha)/0xFF) + ((bred*(0xFF-alpha))/0xFF);
    COLOR green = ((cgreen*alpha)/0xFF) + ((bgreen*(0xFF-alpha))/0xFF);
    COLOR blue = ((cblue*alpha)/0xFF) + ((bblue*(0xFF-alpha))/0xFF);

    return red << 16 | green << 8 | blue;
}
```

GCC Compile Line --->

```
gcc <source-file> -lX11 -o <executable-file>
```

Here is what happens when the first example image is loaded and the Canvas_Draw() function is called less than 13 times --->

[image]

Here is what happens when the first example image is loaded and the Canvas_Draw() function is called 13 times or more --->

[image]

Here is what happens when the second example image is loaded and the Canvas_Draw() function is called 1 time or more --->

[image]

Here is a link to both of the testable images in a compressed zip folder --->

[Images.zip](http://www.mediafire.com/file/n7fc0n9tlc0w0at)

If anyone can figure out what the problem is and help me out, I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Since `Canvas_Draw()` is not a standard function, you really should provide its code (or a shortened version that still has this problem), otherwise how can we help?

Comment: That's old XWindows tech, but IIRC at some point you probably have to enter in the main callback function to be sure you get a refresh. `XFlush` may do the job, but in that case it seems that it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, XFlush isn't the issue...

Comment: Why are you using x11 directly? Why not use SDL2 or Gtk3

Comment: @unwind I did, it's the third code chunk.

Comment: @Erik W Because I want to code without the help of libraries. I aim to write my own operating system at some point, and I want to get the feel of writing code from the ground up. Though I am not quite ready for machine level programming just yet. This is why I am practicing at this level right now.

Comment: @ErikW At some point I want to be able to write code solely on machine level.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. Ok, but I am going to need some time...

Comment: @n.m. I have provided a verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event loop is broken.

First, you need to select exposure events for your window:

```
XSelectInput(display, canvas.canvas, KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask |
                                     ButtonPressMask | StructureNotifyMask |
                                     ExposureMask); // <===== here
```

Second, you only need to draw when your event indicates that you need to draw:

```
while(1) {
    XNextEvent(display, &event);

    if (event.type == Expose &&                   // <=== not on other events
        event.xexpose.window == canvas.canvas) {  // <=== not on events from other windows
      Canvas_Draw(display, &canvas);
      continue;
    }
```

This shows your image on first call to `Canvas_Draw`.

A window is ready to be drawn when its first expose event arrives. There is no point in trying to draw before that. Premature requests may or may not do what you want.

After that, you are free to redraw on button presses or whatever else you want.

Comment: Thank you! Though, is the "continue;" line of code within the expose event really necessary? If so, why?

Comment: About `continue` -- you are done with the expose event at this point. Other events need their own `if (event.type == ...)` and/or  `if (event.xexpose.window = ...)` You might as well skip these checks. Of course you can use a switch or some other dispatch mechanism instead.